# How to compare the html content of 2 divs with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am comparing the html of 2 different divs and works perfect, but if the content is very long then doesnt work.

```
if ($('#Div1').html().trim() == $('#Div2').html().trim()) { 
    console.log("Divs are identical");
}
else{
    console.log("Divs are different");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4r6no12y/

Comment: The jQuery code you've got will work. The issue you have is that the HTML you're outputting is completely invalid and is breaking the structure of the page, so that `<div id="Div2">` isn't actually being rendered at all. Also note that the fiddle itself wasn't referencing jQuery, here's a corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/4r6no12y/. You can see that `$(''Div2').html()` is outputting nothing. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, with that much HTML, but I'm certain there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Code seems fine to me - but the HTML is screwed up - you have the end of `<head>` inside the div, without an opening, and then an entire website. this seems like a lazy example, where you basically just copied the inspect code and threw ins - If you use your fiddle with valid html, the script works as intended

Comment: The html code to compare was copied from aleatory site and copy/paste 3 times.
I tested 1 or 2 repetitions and works. Its cos I think the error is caused by the string length not due html. You can check your own well formed html (repeating to formed a very long html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a problem with Jquery html() function.
You can assign the html content to a js variable and check it

```
var Div1 = $('#Div1').html().trim();
var Div2 = $('#Div2').html().trim();

if ( Div1 == Div2 ) { 
    console.log("Divs are identical");
}
else{
    console.log("Divs are different");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qLszd904/